# Image uploaded by users is not being inserted to the table

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-into

Everything but the $sqlImg (which is supposed to insert the uploaded image to the table) is working. Can someone explain it to me why it isn't working? Or if there's another way that works, I would love to hear it. The file below is my upload.inc.php. I'm planning to echo the image on another file called home.php once it is inserted to my table.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();}

include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$id = $_SESSION['key'];

if (isset($_POST['submitFile'])) {
$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $file['name'];
$fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $file['size'];
$fileError = $file['error'];
$fileType = $file['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));


$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError == 0) {
        if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
            $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

            $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id';";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            $sqlImg = "INSERT INTO profileimg (image) WHERE userid='$id' VALUES ($fileNameNew);";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);

            header("Location: home.php?upload=success");
        }
        else { echo "Sorry, your file size is too big.";}
    }
    else { echo "Oops, an error occurred!";}
}
else { echo "Please upload png and jpg files only.";}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `INSERT` on the new image. I think you need `UPDATE` instead.

**Change:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id';";
```

**To:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0, image = '$fileNameNew' WHERE userid='$id';";
```

**And remove:**

```
$sqlImg = "INSERT INTO profileimg (image) WHERE userid='$id' VALUES ($fileNameNew);";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
```

You are doing session_start() the wrong way. It should be called all a time.

**Change:**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();}
```

**To:**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: When I changed it to "session_start();" this error appeared again: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\wamp\www\FormFinalPush\upload.php on line 3. That's why I used "if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();}" instead.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: But anyway, thank you so muuuch! It worked, the picture is now inserted to my table. :)

Comment: Ohh, this is the first time that I encountered that, thank you for the knowledge that you have imparted! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlImg = "INSERT INTO profileimg (image) WHERE userid='$id' VALUES ($fileNameNew);";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
```

should be

```
$sqlImg = "INSERT INTO profileimg (image) WHERE userid=".$id." VALUES (".$fileNameNew.")";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
```